# Struggling with using Python to parse and manipulate XML file with content from external text files

Tags: python, xml, excel, wordpress, parsing

I've been spending over a couple of months trying to accomplish the following.

I have an Excel-generated XML file that captures a database that I've been working on to build a website.  The dream is to have this or some manipulated form of this XML file to import into WordPress so I no longer have to manually edit each post or web page one-by-one (especially when I make a change that affects the content of several or all pages/posts in the website).

The Excel file (which I'm calling 'test_of_2016-09-19.xml') looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Bridalveil Fall</Waterfall_Name>
        <Continent___Super_Region>North America</Continent___Super_Region>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <State___Province>California</State___Province>
        <Subregion>Southern and Central Sierras</Subregion>
        <locale___political_or_official>Mariposa County</locale___political_or_official>
        <alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>Yosemite National Park</alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>
        <Misc__Tags>oakhurst, el portal, mariposa, yosemite, yosemite valley, sierra, california, waterfall, fresno, modesto, wawona, tunnel, merced, pohono, wheelchair</Misc__Tags>
        <scenic_rating>4.5</scenic_rating>
        <difficulty_rating>1</difficulty_rating>
        <distance>roadside; 1/2 mile round trip to base; wheelchair</distance>
        <time_commitment>20 minutes</time_commitment>
        <GPS_Coordinates>37.71736, -119.64901</GPS_Coordinates>
        <date_first_visited>1999-09-04</date_first_visited>
        <date_last_visited>2011-06-04</date_last_visited>
        <Old_Web_Address>http://www.world-of-waterfalls.com/yosemite-bridalveil-fall.html</Old_Web_Address>
        <Post_Slug>yosemite-bridalveil-fall.html</Post_Slug>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>52</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Switzer Falls</Waterfall_Name>
        <Continent___Super_Region>North America</Continent___Super_Region>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <State___Province>California</State___Province>
        <Subregion>Southern California</Subregion>
        <locale___political_or_official>Los Angeles County</locale___political_or_official>
        <alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>Angeles National Forest, La Canada Flintridge</alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>
        <Misc__Tags>la canada, flintridge, altadena, pasadena, san gabriel, angeles national forest, angeles crest, los angeles, southern california, california, waterfall, arroyo seco, gabrielino trail, clear creek station, adventure pass, picnic</Misc__Tags>
        <scenic_rating>2</scenic_rating>
        <difficulty_rating>3.5</difficulty_rating>
        <distance>4.6 miles round trip (to base of main drop)</distance>
        <time_commitment>3.5 hours (to base of main drop)</time_commitment>
        <GPS_Coordinates>34.25828, -118.15474</GPS_Coordinates>
        <date_first_visited>2003-02-02</date_first_visited>
        <date_last_visited>2016-04-23</date_last_visited>
        <Old_Web_Address>http://www.world-of-waterfalls.com/california-switzer-falls.html</Old_Web_Address>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction>
        <Directions>directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions>
        <Nearby_Waterfalls_Tags>southern california, pasadena, angeles crest, waterfall</Nearby_Waterfalls_Tags>
        <Itinerary_Tags>itinerary, switzer falls</Itinerary_Tags>
        <Trip_Report_Tags>trip report, switzer falls</Trip_Report_Tags>
        <Trip_Planning_Article_Tags>featured article, switzer falls</Trip_Planning_Article_Tags>
        <Post_Slug>california-switzer-falls.html</Post_Slug>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>657</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Detian Waterfall (德天瀑布 [Détiān Pùbù])</Waterfall_Name>
        <Continent___Super_Region>Asia</Continent___Super_Region>
        <Country>China</Country>
        <locale___political_or_official>Guangxi</locale___political_or_official>
        <alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>Daxin County</alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>
        <Misc__Tags>daxin, guichin river, guangxi, vietnam, china, waterfall, ban gioc, transnational, border</Misc__Tags>
        <scenic_rating>4</scenic_rating>
        <difficulty_rating>1.5</difficulty_rating>
        <distance>1km round trip</distance>
        <time_commitment>30-45 minutes</time_commitment>
        <GPS_Coordinates>22.85577, 106.72273</GPS_Coordinates>
        <date_first_visited>2009-04-23</date_first_visited>
        <date_last_visited>2009-04-23</date_last_visited>
        <Old_Web_Address>http://www.world-of-waterfalls.com/asia-detian-waterfall.html</Old_Web_Address>
        <Post_Slug>asia-detian-waterfall.html</Post_Slug>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1125</Entry_No>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1126</Entry_No>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1127</Entry_No>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

What I'm trying to do is that if particular Elements or tags exist (particularly File_directory, Introduction, Directions), then open the pointed-to files, grab their text contents, and place them in new Elements or tags like Introduction_Body, Directions_Body, etc.), then write out the new modified XML file.

The new XML file would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Bridalveil Fall</Waterfall_Name>
        <Continent___Super_Region>North America</Continent___Super_Region>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <State___Province>California</State___Province>
        <Subregion>Southern and Central Sierras</Subregion>
        <locale___political_or_official>Mariposa County</locale___political_or_official>
        <alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>Yosemite National Park</alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>
        <Misc__Tags>oakhurst, el portal, mariposa, yosemite, yosemite valley, sierra, california, waterfall, fresno, modesto, wawona, tunnel, merced, pohono, wheelchair</Misc__Tags>
        <scenic_rating>4.5</scenic_rating>
        <difficulty_rating>1</difficulty_rating>
        <distance>roadside; 1/2 mile round trip to base; wheelchair</distance>
        <time_commitment>20 minutes</time_commitment>
        <GPS_Coordinates>37.71736, -119.64901</GPS_Coordinates>
        <date_first_visited>1999-09-04</date_first_visited>
        <date_last_visited>2011-06-04</date_last_visited>
        <Old_Web_Address>http://www.world-of-waterfalls.com/yosemite-bridalveil-fall.html</Old_Web_Address>
        <Post_Slug>yosemite-bridalveil-fall.html</Post_Slug>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>52</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Switzer Falls</Waterfall_Name>
        <Continent___Super_Region>North America</Continent___Super_Region>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <State___Province>California</State___Province>
        <Subregion>Southern California</Subregion>
        <locale___political_or_official>Los Angeles County</locale___political_or_official>
        <alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>Angeles National Forest, La Canada Flintridge</alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>
        <Misc__Tags>la canada, flintridge, altadena, pasadena, san gabriel, angeles national forest, angeles crest, los angeles, southern california, california, waterfall, arroyo seco, gabrielino trail, clear creek station, adventure pass, picnic</Misc__Tags>
        <scenic_rating>2</scenic_rating>
        <difficulty_rating>3.5</difficulty_rating>
        <distance>4.6 miles round trip (to base of main drop)</distance>
        <time_commitment>3.5 hours (to base of main drop)</time_commitment>
        <GPS_Coordinates>34.25828, -118.15474</GPS_Coordinates>
        <date_first_visited>2003-02-02</date_first_visited>
        <date_last_visited>2016-04-23</date_last_visited>
        <Old_Web_Address>http://www.world-of-waterfalls.com/california-switzer-falls.html</Old_Web_Address>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction>
        <Introduction_Body>This would be text from the file ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/introduction-switzer-falls.html complete with links, img tags, and other lorem ipsum; would I need to do anything special for special characters like Chinese and Japanese Characters, accent markings, etc?</Introduction_Body>
        <Directions>directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions>
        <Directions_Body>This would be text from the file ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/directions-switzer-falls.html complete with links, img tags, and other lorem ipsum; would I need to do anything special for special characters like Chinese and Japanese Characters, accent markings, etc?</Directions_Body>
        <Nearby_Waterfalls_Tags>southern california, pasadena, angeles crest, waterfall</Nearby_Waterfalls_Tags>
        <Itinerary_Tags>itinerary, switzer falls</Itinerary_Tags>
        <Trip_Report_Tags>trip report, switzer falls</Trip_Report_Tags>
        <Trip_Planning_Article_Tags>featured article, switzer falls</Trip_Planning_Article_Tags>
        <Post_Slug>california-switzer-falls.html</Post_Slug>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>657</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Detian Waterfall (德天瀑布 [Détiān Pùbù])</Waterfall_Name>
        <Continent___Super_Region>Asia</Continent___Super_Region>
        <Country>China</Country>
        <locale___political_or_official>Guangxi</locale___political_or_official>
        <alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>Daxin County</alt__locale__unofficial_or_more_recognized>
        <Misc__Tags>daxin, guichin river, guangxi, vietnam, china, waterfall, ban gioc, transnational, border</Misc__Tags>
        <scenic_rating>4</scenic_rating>
        <difficulty_rating>1.5</difficulty_rating>
        <distance>1km round trip</distance>
        <time_commitment>30-45 minutes</time_commitment>
        <GPS_Coordinates>22.85577, 106.72273</GPS_Coordinates>
        <date_first_visited>2009-04-23</date_first_visited>
        <date_last_visited>2009-04-23</date_last_visited>
        <Old_Web_Address>http://www.world-of-waterfalls.com/asia-detian-waterfall.html</Old_Web_Address>
        <Post_Slug>asia-detian-waterfall.html</Post_Slug>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1125</Entry_No>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1126</Entry_No>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1127</Entry_No>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

With some guidance from someone in this forum, I was able to at least get so far with the following code:

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

data_file = 'test_of_2016-09-19.xml'

tree = ET.ElementTree(file=data_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root:
    if element.find('File_directory') is not None: 
        directory = element.find('File_directory').text
    if element.find('Introduction') is not None:
        introduction = element.find('Introduction').text
    if element.find('Directions') is not None:
        directions = element.find('Directions').text

    #The following code was suggested to me, but I'm having trouble getting them to work and understanding what each line is doing
    intro_tree = ET.ElementTree(directory+introduction) #throws NameError: name 'ET' is not defined
    intro_text = intro_tree.find('body').text #won't work since intro_tree not defined, but even then, I'm not sure what this line is trying to do
    intro = SubElement(element,'Introduction') #throws NameError: name 'SubElement' is not defined
    intro.text = intro_text #didn't get this far, but what is the intent of this line?
    # Do the same for Directions
    directions_tree = ET.ElementTree(directory+directions)
    directions_text = directions_tree.find('body').text
    directions = SubElement(element,'Direction')

# After the loop, write the file back with new elements added
tree.write('new_' + data_file)
```

Because I'm new to Python, I'm having lots of difficulty trying to do what appears to be this simple task, but I feel like I'm flying blind given my ignorance in the syntax and the right keywords and/or methods or even libraries to use.  Is there an easier way to do this?  Am I correct in using Python with XML using the ElementTree Library for this job?  Or is lxml or minidom better?  I really don't know and all the literature out there is confusing given all the options and my lack of background in Python.

Any help to try to get me through this impasse would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Johnny

Comment: What happens if element.find() doesn't find anything and returns none? 
What happens if you try to concatinate None with a str? 
What happens if you try to call ET.ElementTree() with None?

Comment: Point taken.  So I tried to do:  for element in root:<br>    if element.find('File_directory') is not None && element.find('Introduction') is not None:<br>        intro_tree = ET.ElementTree(directory+introduction)<br>, but apparently this is invalid syntax.  Not sure how I can combine logical statements in Python for this case